# Entity Framework Code First IQueryable

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

I am using Entity Framework Code First and ran into a small road block.  I have a class "Person" defined as such:

```
public class Person
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<History> History { get; set; }
}
```

and a class "History" defined as such:

```
public class History
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Owner { get; set; }
    public DateTime OnDate { get; set; }
}
```

However, when I call:

```
IEnumerable<History> results = person.History
                               .OrderBy(h => h.OnDate)
                               .Take(50)
                               .ToArray();
```

It appears to pull all of the history for the person, then order it and such in memory.  Any recommendations on what I'm missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What behavior were you expecting to see? Is it failing to limit the result to 50 records?

Comment: I think the expected behaviour is to order it in the database

Comment: I was expecting it to send the order by and limit to the server, causing SQL server to do the ordering and limiting.  Instead, it appears to pull all the history into memory, all 30,000+ elements for that contact and then doing the order and limit in memory.

Comment: Why are you sure it's loading it in memory? have you seen the generated sql?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are querying an `IEnumerable` (ie: LINQ to Objects) not `IQueryable` (ie: LINQ to Entities) given by EF.

Instead you should use

```
IEnumerable<History> results = context.History.Where(h => h.Person.Id = "sfssd").OrderBy(h => h.OnDate).Take(50)
```

Comment: This is EF code first - it is assumed that `Person` was retrieved from the DB, hence its navigation property `History` is connected to the context.

Comment: @BrokenGlass yes it is connected. But its of type `ICollection<History>` not `IQueryable<History>`. So when you access `person.History` it will load all history objects.

Comment: Ah you are right of course since lazy loading will kick in and load the full collection. Got my +1

Comment: That's too bad.  I guess it all makes sense, I was just hoping there was a way to do it this way.  There's an idea for EF 5... IQueryableCollection.  :-)

Comment: You could always write a [NotMapped] property that did the IQueryable stuff under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

This question and the accepted answer are both a bit old. Code like this would, as the original question points, load the entire history for the person from the database - not good!

```
var results = person
    .History
    .OrderBy(h => h.OnDate)
    .Take(50)
    .ToArray();
```

**With EF 6** there is an easy solution.  Without rearranging your query, you can have it work the `IQueryable` way by making use of the [`DbContext.Entry` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696578(v=vs.113).aspx), the [`DbEntryEntity.Collection` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671324(v=vs.113).aspx), and the [`DbCollectionEntry.Query` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696278(v=vs.113).aspx).

```
var results = dbContext
    .Entry(person)
    .Collection(p => p.History)
    .Query()
    .OrderBy(h => h.OnDate)
    .Take(50)
    .ToArray();
```