# Does AsQueryable() on ICollection really makes lazy execution?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, iqueryable, icollection

I am using Entity Framework CodeFirst where I have used Parent Child relations using ICollection as

```
public class Person
{
   public string UserName { get;set}
   public ICollection<Blog> Blogs { get; set;}
}

public class Blog
{
   public int id { get; set; }
   public string Subject { get; set; }
   public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

Ok, so far everything is working ok, but my concern is, whenever I want to get the Blogs of a person, I get it as

```
var thePerson = _context.Persons.Where(x => x.UserName = 'xxx').SingleOrDefault();
var theBlogs = thePerson.Blogs.OrderBy(id).Take(5);
```

Now, I understand that, when the line is executed, all Blogs for that person is loaded into the memory and then sorting and selecting is done from memory. That is not ideal for a record of Person who has large number of blogs. I want to make the Blog Child as IQueryable so that the Sorting and Selecting is done in SQL database before pulling to Memory.

I know I could declare the Blogs as IQueryable in my context so that I could directly query as

```
var theBlogs = _context.Blogs.Where(.....)
```

but that is not feasible for me due to design choice, I want to avoid any circular reference as much as possible due to serialization problem. So, I did not make any reference of the parent entity in my child.

I found that, i can call AsQueryable() method on the blogs as

```
var theBlogs = thePerson.Blogs.AsQueryable().OrderBy(id).Take(5);
```

That looks like a magic for me and seems too good to be true. So my question. Does this AsQueryable really make the ICollection as IQueryable in reality and makes all Query process in SQL Server (Lazy loading) OR it is just a casting where Blogs are loaded into memory as like before, but change the interface from ICollection to IQueryable ?

Comment: Thanks – Enigmativity, so my suspicion was true then. it is sad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So actually it appears that writing your navigation property as `IQueryable<T>` [is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551988/entity-framework-4-many-to-many-relationship-iqueryable-instead-of-icollection).

What you could do is adding a navigation property to `Blog`:

```
public class Blog
{
   public int id { get; set; }
   public string Subject { get; set; }
   public string Body { get; set; }
   public virtual Person Owner { get; set; }
}
```

From that, you can query as follows so it won't load everything into memory:

```
var thePerson = _context.Persons.Where(x => x.UserName = 'xxx').SingleOrDefault();
var results = _context.Blogs.Where(z => z.Person.Name = thePerson.Name).OrderBy(id).Take(5)
```

I suggest you to try [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) to see how LINQ is translated into SQL, and what is actually requested from the DB.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Ok, so does it mean, ICollection is also a lazy loader like IQueryable and I can safely use ICollection anywhere in place of IQueryable where I want the query should take place in database ? About LINQPAD, I think that gives therotical idea about what is the SQL translation, but maybe some EntityFramework Profiler can help better to see what QUERY is actully being sent in the database. I dont have any Entity Framework profiler, but now I am looking into some products like that.

Comment: Just another question, so if my previous question's answer is YES, then, I dont need to use AsQueryable() anymore for ICollection, right ?

Comment: +1 for recommending a tool that makes developing LINQ queries easier.

Comment: @EmranH. Please see updated answer. From your comment, I realized I think I've misread your question a bit...
For LINQPad, I really recommend it, it's very useful and returns the SQL that will be run against your DB. Of course you can profile your DB (using SQL Server Profiler for instance), but it'll returns same results and require your code to be compiled (LINQPad, in the other hand, allows writing some piece of code on-the-fly).

Comment: Hi Ken2k, thank you again for your kind replies. Actually adding the Parent as navigation property to child creates Circular Reference, which is problem for 2 reasons. 1. It violates the Domain Driven Design Patterns, DDD suggests that, I should traverse to Child from parent, not directly. 2. Although #1 is not that big problem as we violate rules time to time, but when serializing the data over wire for WCF/JSON/AJAX load, serializers cannot serialize the circular reference entities. So, my question, is there any other alternatives available for lazy loading childs ?

Comment: @EmranH. I don't think (1) is a problem. When using Model-first approach, both navigation properties are added per default by EF, which actually adds a circular reference. If EF does it this way, it should be OK. For (2), you could annotate navigation properties to be ignored by serializers (`[XmlIgnoreAttribute]`, `[SoapIgnoreAttribute]`...).

Comment: Hi @Ken2K. Thank you for the insights. I marked this question as Answered. - Regards.

Comment: @EmranH. Here are some information about how to accept answers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235 Maybe there are some specific cases where it's not possible?

Answer (score 3):

A better approach is described in [Ladislav's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7552985/62024). In your case:

```
var theBlogs = _context.Entry(thePerson)
                       .Collection(x => x.Blogs)
                       .Query()
                       .OrderBy(x => x.id)
                       .Take(5);
```