# Why is there no WHERE clause in SQL query?

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent

I have a strange problem. I noticed that the code defined below:

```
var query= unitOfWork.Session.CreateCriteria(typeof (SomeEntity)).Future<SomeEntity>().AsQueryable();
var queryWithWhere= query.Where(x => x.SomeProperty.ToLower().Contains("Xxx".ToLower()));
var result= queryWithWhere.ToList();
```

gives proper result but the SQL query I watched in NHibernateProfiler doesn't contain where clause, it's just

```
SELECT ... 
FROM SomeEntity
```

and it seems that this `WHERE` from my code is is used after the SQL query runs, just like Linq-to-Objects instead of Linq-to-SQL.

And of course the SQL query is started after the third line is proceeded.

Comment: What is the SQL query that is generated?

Comment: It's like this: select [all columns] from SomeEntity; - no WHERE clause

Comment: Check my answer, it will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Linq, and for NHibernate to *understand it*, then use the `CreateQuery<T>` extension (part of NHibernate, in the `NHibernate.Linq` namespace) to directly create an `IQueryable<T>`, rather than using `CreateCriteria<T>` - which, as you have noticed, only lets you write the parts of your query that NHibernate will process as restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the WHERE inside the first query I think you need to add a Restriction:

```
 unitOfWork.Session.CreateCriteria<SomeEntity>()
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("SomeProperty", "Some Value"))
```

Cheers

**EDIT**

Or more suitable for you

```
 unitOfWork.Session.CreateCriteria<SomeEntity>()
    .Add(Restrictions.InsensitiveLike("SomeProperty", "Some Value"))
```

Comment: But what about LinQ solution, I don't want to use Resrictions, only LinQ and then materialize it

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate is materializing the results set due to the `AsQueryable()` which causes the collection to be loaded and cast as IQueryable. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191094/does-asqueryable-on-icollection-really-makes-lazy-execution) for similar behavior in Entity Framework.

I would re-write your query to use NHibernate's LINQ provider:

```
var result = session.Query<SomeEntity>()
                    .Where(x => x.SomeProperty.ToLower().Contains("Xxx".ToLower)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go in `QueryOver<T>` in your place and add `NHibernate.Criterion` in your usings. Code would look like this:

```
    using NHibernate.Criterion;
    //...
    var result = session.QueryOver<SomeEntity>()
        .Where(e => e.SomeProperty
            .IsLike("xyz", MatchMode.Anywhere)).List().ToList();
```

It will generate query as you want.