# EntityFramework: Linq on SQL: Contains or IndexOf?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

I have a weird situation regarding EntityFramework 6 with .NET 4.5 (C#).

I have (almost) the same query in two different places. But one time it queries agains the database and the second time it queries against in-memory objects. And since I'm filtering for a substring, this is a crucial difference:

Database structure are tables Role, Right and a cross-table Role_Right

First time around I want to find all available rights that are not already assigned to the role plus (and that's where it gets complicated) a manual filter to reduce the result list:

```
Role role = ...;
string filter = ...;
var roleRightNames = role.Right.Select(roleRight => roleRight.RightName);
var filteredRights = context.Right.Where(right => !roleRightNames.Contains(right.RightName));
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter))
{
    filteredRights = filteredRights.Where(e => e.RightName.Contains(filter));
}
var result = filteredRights.ToList();
```

I cannot use `IndexOf(filter, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)` because this cannot be translated to SQL. But I'm fine with `Contains` because it produces the desired result (see below).

When enabling the SQL output I get:

```
SELECT [Extent1].[RightName] AS [RightName]
FROM [dbo].[Right] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ( NOT ([Extent1].[RightName] IN ('Right_A1', 'Right_A2', 'Right_B1'))) AND ([Extent1].[RightName] LIKE @p__linq__0 ESCAPE '~'
-- p__linq__0: '%~_a%' (Type = AnsiString, Size = 8000)
```

Which is exactly what I want, a case-insensitive search on the filter "_a" to find for example 'Right_A3'

The second time I want to filter the existing associated rights for the same filter:

```
Role role = ...;
string filter = ...;
var filteredRights = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter)
    ? role.Right
    : role.Right.Where(e => e.RightName.IndexOf(filter, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);            
var result = filteredRights.ToList();
```

This time it forces me to use `IndexOf` because it uses the `Contains` method of the `string` instead of translating it to an SQL `LIKE` and `string.Contains` is case-sensitive.

My problem is that I cannot - from looking at the code - predict when a query is executed against the database and when it is done in-memory and since I cannot use `IndexOf` in the first query and `Contains` in the second this seems to be a bit unpredictable to me. What happens when one day the second query is executed first and the data is not already in-memory?

**Edit 10 Feb 2020**

OK, so I figured out what the main difference is. `context.Right` is of type `DbSet` which is an `IQueryable` and so is the subsequent extension method `Where`. However `userRole.Right` returns an `ICollection` which is an `IEnumerable` and so is the subsequent `Where`. Is there a way to make the relationship property of an entity object to an `IQueryable`? `AsQueryable` did not work. Which means that all associated `Right` entities are always gotten from the database before doing an in-memory `Where`.
We're not talking about huge amounts of data and at least now this behaviour is predictable, but I find it unfortunate nonetheless.

Comment: well.. this question is in regards to Lazy\Immediate Loading of Linq Expressions, with consideration to supported type methods for LinqToSql compiling.

Comment: Can you fix or clarify the line regarding "This time I need to use `IndexOf` because it uses the `string.Contains` ... " ... *apart from the line being unclear*, there is also a misconception being made here, the SQL `LIKE` operation is neither case-sensitive nor case-insensitive - the collation on the column as it relates to the table would be the determent factor there. you would handle case-insensitive checks here in the same regards as you would in SQL, toLower or toLowerVariant

Comment: @BrettCaswell I clarified the sentence. Apart from that I only ever worked with database that are case-insensitive, so I never thought about that case.

Comment: OK, so I figured out what the main difference is. `context.Right` is of type `DbSet` which is an `IQueryable` and so is the subsequent extension method `Where`. However `userRole.Right` returns an `ICollection` which is an `IEnumerable` and so is the subsequent `Where`. Is there a way to make the relationship property of an entity object to an `IQueryable`? `AsQueryable` did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I found two different solutions to always query against the database in case a relation contains a huge result set. Both solutions are not directly intuitive - IMHO - and you will need the `DbContext` variable which you hadn't needed before.

Solution one is using the `Role` table as a starting point and simply filtering for the entity with the correct Id.
**Note** You cannot use `Single` because then you deal with a single entity object and you're right back where you've started. You need to use `Where` and then a `SelectMany` even though it's counter-intuitive:

```
Role role = ...;
string filter = ...;
var filteredRights = context.Role.Where(e => e.RoleId == userRole.RoleId).SelectMany(e => e.Right);
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter))
{
    filteredRights = filteredRights.Where(e => e.RightName.Contains(filter));
}
var rights = filteredRights.ToList();
```

which results in an SQL query against the DB:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[RightName] AS [RightName]
    FROM [dbo].[Role_Right] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[RoleId] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[RightName] LIKE @p__linq__1 ESCAPE '~')
-- p__linq__0: '42' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)
-- p__linq__1: '%~_a%' (Type = AnsiString, Size = 8000)
```

The second solution I found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7552985/2334520

In my case this results in:

```
Role role = ...;
string filter = ...;
var filteredRights = context.Entry(userRole).Collection(e => e.Right).Query();
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter))
{
    filteredRights = filteredRights.Where(e => e.RightName.Contains(filter));
}
var rights = filteredRights.ToList();
```

and SQL

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[RightName] AS [RightName]
    FROM [dbo].[Role_Right] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[RoleId] = @EntityKeyValue1) AND ([Extent1].[RightName] LIKE @p__linq__0 ESCAPE '~')
-- EntityKeyValue1: '42' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)
-- p__linq__0: '%~_a%' (Type = AnsiString, Size = 8000)
```

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is that I cannot - from looking at the code - predict when
>   a query is executed against the database and when it is done in-memory
>   and since I cannot use IndexOf in the first query and Contains in the
>   second this seems to be a bit unpredictable to me.

You can use `IndexOf` and `Contains` in both queries, as long as you don't use the overload featuring a `StringComparison`. As pointed by @BrettCaswell, the case matching is fixed by the collation of your Database/Table/Column.
A query will be translated to SQL if its root is a context's `DbSet` and all method calls are translatable to SQL.

As soon as a method cannot be translated, the current state request is performed at SQL level and the remainder of the query is performed in the memory of the .Net application.

Also I think that `p__linq__0` value should be `'%~_a%'` as `_` is a special character in `LIKE` clauses.

Comment: Thx, I will try out what happens if I don't use `StringComparison`. As for the underscore, I faked the data a bit and just used the `_a` as an example. The SQL translator does it right.

Comment: OK, so I tried out `IndexOf` without `StringComparison` where I know that it is turned into an SQL and it indeed works.
Problem is - and here's where we get to the original problem - when I use `IndexOf` in the second query without `StringComparison` I end up right where I started as in I don't get any data (just like with `Contains`). So I still need to know when the query goes against the datbase and when against the string class. Which is unfortunate.