# Entity Framework One To Many IQueryable

Tags: c#, .net, orm, entity-framework-6

So, i was jugglin with this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/entity_framework/entity_framework_first_example.htm) as i need to optimize some queries. However, i realized on one to many relation EF tend to retrieve all related rows first and further queries done in memory - somewhat inefficient and might chew your memory into the last bits. Is there any way (or best practice) to hook one to many (or perhaps many to many) relations in EF that returns [IQueryable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of ICollection?

Basic EF one to many

```
public class parent
{
   [Key]
   public int ParentId;
   public string Name;
   public virtual ICollection<Child> Childs;
}

public class Child
{
  [Key]
  public int ChildId;
  public string Name;
  public int ParentId;
  [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
  Public Parent Parent;
}
```

Well, as a bit background information, i come from [Laravel](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Relation.html). Perhaps it just me expecting the non-existent on C#.Net. But heck doing a Linq on 3000+ records in memory is no fun, especially if you'll only take few of them. Does i am missing something? I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470278/entity-framework-code-first-iqueryable) querstion, it just simply unsightly to throw `.Where` by id for retrieving relations as it will scatter (and obsecure) the very definition of ORM - make keys management centralized and upper layer did not required to know what defines the relation of the object. Please, enlighten me.

**Edit**
Thanks whoever down voted this. I really appreciate it. Cheers.

Comment: No, it is not done in memory - that's the point. IQueryable defers execution. Read up on that plus lazy loading and paging (.Take()). http://www.developerhandbook.com/entity-framework/in-the-spotlight-demystifying-iqueryable-entity-framework-6/

Comment: the `public virtual ICollection<Child> Childs;` deferred? well, if that was the case, i should notice no difference in execution time between `ICollection` and `IQueryable`. Although i know using `IQueryable` had its drawbacks - unlike `IEnumerable` where lots method available cause it's on App side.

Comment: You mean you wish to do something like Parend.Childs.Where without actually loading all Childs elements to memory to perform the filter?

Comment: yep, perhaps me asking too much. for now i put `.where` criterion almost everywhere. but now i am stuck on many-to-many relationship..

Comment: as far as I know, there's no built-in way to do that. Once you access a navigation property, the whole collection will be loaded. What I usually do is something like this: ChildsSet.Where(c => parentId = id && <your filter>). This would bring only the rows you need. I have a Get method on my repositories that allow me to do that kind of query easily. This is a real big problem. Just recently I had to rewrite a big chunk of code because people in the project have been using X.someLazyLoadedProperty.Where all over the place, but the collections where like 20MB, so yeah...

Comment: ah well, thank you @victor. at least i can confirm there is no other *clean* way to do it... i should suggest using repository pattern for new projects then.