# EF Core: Many to many using collection of IDs (instead of using collection of entities)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Is there a way to specify many to many relationship only by using collection of IDs like so:

```
class Notification
{
   ...
   public ICollection<Guid> UsersIds { get; set; }
}

class User
{
   ...
   public ICollection<Guid> NotificationsIds { get; set; }
}
```

**Why do we need this:** in our application there is a many to many relationship between User and Notification. By having only IDs reference to other aggregate instead of the object we want to avoid performance problems when a lot of objects get loaded into memory.

Comment: [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many) are quite clear: *"Many-to-many relationships **require** a **collection navigation property** on **both** sides"*. Collections of IDs are *not* navigation properties, so...

Comment: i've been asking the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40823334/entity-framework-one-to-many-iqueryable) sometime in the past, but the answer is simply no. we have to work around using `.Where(x => h.Id = "something")` to avoid memory troubles.