# How to update an object containing a list of IDs of related objects?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I have a many-to-many relationship for which I have three tables: a table for each of the two classes of objects and a third table for the associations with a column for IDs of the first object type and an ID column for the second.

One of the classes in my C# code has a property which is a List and contains IDs of the other class's objects.

I want to update an object in a table and also update relationships in the association table based on the provided IDs which means, some of those relationships will need to be deleted and some new added. Is there a way to do this automatically in EntityFrameworkCore?

```
public class Student
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<string> CourseIds {get;set;}
}

public class Course
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
}
```

The association table:

```
studentid, courseid
```

A student can attend multiple courses but also multiple students can attend a course, hence the many-to-many relationship here. I'm trying to update a student, along with the related courses in the list of IDs.

Comment: Does this article help? https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/updating-many-to-many-relationships-in-ef-core-5-and-above/#direct-many-to-many-usage-add-a-new-link

Comment: *Is there a way to do this automatically in EntityFrameworkCore?* -- no, because this is not a healthy database design and it will cause you a lot of trouble. Use a junction table `CourseStudent` and EF will nod approvingly.

Comment: This database design was generated by EF itself and I do have a StudentCourse table. That's the one containing the studentid and the courseid.

Comment: Generated by EF? Never seen that. Which database provider is this? Either way, if you have a junction table then what's the use of this redundant list of Ids?

Answer (score 0):

As described in [this article](https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/updating-many-to-many-relationships-in-ef-core-5-and-above/#direct-many-to-many-usage-add-a-new-link) there is multiple ways to do that.
I would do it like this:

```cs
public class Student
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public ICollection<Course> Courses {get;set;}
}

public class Course
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public ICollection<Student> Students {get;set;}
}
```

This sets up your many-to-many relationship. You can then define your linking table:

```cs
public class StudentCourse
{
  public string StudentId {get;set;}
  public string CourseId{get;set;}

  public Student Student {get;set;}
  public Course Course {get;set;}
}
```

and set it up in the OnModelCreating method:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().HasMany(x => x.Classes)
  .WithMany(x => x.Students)
  .UsingEntity<StudentCourse>(
    x => x.HasOne(x => x.Course)
    .WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.Id),
    x => x.HasOne(x => x.Student)
    .WithMany().HasForeignkey(x => x.Id));
```

You should then be able to directly interact with those lists for example like this:

```cs
// coursesToAdd is predefined somewhere
Student student = new Student();
foreach(Course course in coursesToAdd) {
  student.Courses.Add(course);
}
```

Comment: I was hoping there would be a way to use the string IDs directly as I'll be sending them from the frontend. I guess, I'll need to instantiate a `Course` object for each ID and add them all to the list in the `Student`'s property so that EF can update the relations correctly?

Comment: It seems like it yeah. [This person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71377879/ef-core-many-to-many-using-collection-of-ids-instead-of-using-collection-of-en)  has asked a similar question and [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many) say it needs collection navigation properties not just ids

Comment: So I tried to add the suggested code to OnModelCreating but the update is still not working and it also broke my reading Students for a Course. Now I get an empty list.